# Trying to edit someone else's code written using vue: Where would the value of the property inside the {{ }} mustache be?

Tags: vue.js, data-binding

The line of code reads similar to:

```
<h1 class="category" v-cloak>{[{category.name}]}</h1>
```

Where does the property `category.name` gets its values from?

I couldn't find it in the script file either.

Comment: Is `{[{ ... }]}` custom mustache syntax? Is the component extending another component, or does it have any mixins? `category` could be a computed property.

Comment: it's really hard to say with only this line, please add more information, and verify if the old dev was using custom delimiters https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#delimiters

Comment: If this is typo over custom syntax, 'category' must be a data or a computed property.